# Create Grids with Dynamic Columns and Data Types( Vue.Js)

Tags: vue.js

I want to create a Grid with column and data-field information that is retrieved during run time in Kendo Vue UI

just like demo here

http://dojo.telerik.com/OkuRe

but in Vue

thanks

i m developer working on kendo vue js

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple where a similar scenario is implemented - https://stackblitz.com/edit/2v8gaj-1azrrk?file=index.js.
You could also check and example with the brand new [Native Kendo Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid-native/) that was just released where dynamic columns are an easy task- https://stackblitz.com/edit/wanzoc?file=index.js .

Greetings,
Plamen